# how to use QThreads without sync

Tags: qt, qthread

I have 3 classes, A, B and C;

Here is class A:
A.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <QObject>

class A : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

public:

    A();

    void doWork();

signals:

    void ready(QString str, QVector<double> v);
};

#endif // A_H
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"

#include <QVector>

A::A() {

}

void A::doWork() {

    QVector<double> x;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 10; i++) {
        x.push_back(i);
    }

    emit ready("A ready", x);
}
```

B and C are exactly the same. Only the loop in doWork in class B is until 10000 and in C until 100000000 (8 zeroes).

Just for the test of using QThreads I created 3 QLabel:

```
QLabel* lbl_a;
QLabel* lbl_b;
QLabel* lbl_c;
```

This is my MainWindow code:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QThread>
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

public slots:

    void handlerA(QString str, QVector<double> v);
    void handlerB(QString str, QVector<double> v);
    void handlerC(QString str, QVector<double> v);


private slots:
    void on_btn_start_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    A* a;
    B* b;
    C* c;
    QThread thread_a;
    QThread thread_b;
    QThread thread_c;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow) {

    ui->setupUi(this);

    a = new A();
    b = new B();
    c = new C();

    a->moveToThread(&thread_a);
    b->moveToThread(&thread_b);
    c->moveToThread(&thread_c);

    connect(a, SIGNAL(ready(QString, QVector<double>)), this, SLOT(handlerA(QString, QVector<double>)));
    connect(b, SIGNAL(ready(QString, QVector<double>)), this, SLOT(handlerB(QString, QVector<double>)));
    connect(c, SIGNAL(ready(QString, QVector<double>)), this, SLOT(handlerC(QString, QVector<double>)));

    thread_a.start();
    thread_b.start();
    thread_c.start();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow() {


    thread_a.wait();
    thread_b.wait();
    thread_c.wait();
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::handlerA(QString str, QVector<double> v) {

    QVector<double> x = v;
    ui->lbl_a->setText(str);
}

void MainWindow::handlerB(QString str, QVector<double> v) {

    QVector<double> x = v;
    ui->lbl_b->setText(str);
}

void MainWindow::handlerC(QString str, QVector<double> v) {

    QVector<double> x = v;
    ui->lbl_c->setText(str);
}

void MainWindow::on_btn_start_clicked() {

    a->doWork();
    b->doWrok();
    c->doWork();
}
```

I expected that lbl_a will appear first and then lbl_b and then lbl_c
but no matter how I change the for loop they always appear together.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing the `for` loops in each thread. You are executing them all in the same thread, the `main` thread.

This is because you are calling directly the function `doWork` from the slot `on_btn_start_clicked`, behaving as a normal function.

You should remove entirely the calls to `doWork`.
Instead, connect the signal `QThread::started()` to your `doWork` function. With this, once the thread has started, it will emit this signal from the new thread, executing your `doWork` function from the thread.

```
connect(&thread_a, &QThread::started, a, &A::doWork);
```

Of course, `a`, `b` and `c` have to be QObjects, and the functions `doWork` must be slots.

---

Note: Starting from Qt 5.10 and C++17, you can use also the static function [QThread::create](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#create), which creates a thread and upon starting, it will execute the passed function.